# Element order option missing

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench

Part of my project is to compare linear elements and quadratic elements with a Quad mesh within Ansys workbench - static structural. The button that my classmates have to change between element orders is missing on my Ansys. Has anyone had ths issue and knows a solution or knows something I need to check to get the button to show? the option should appear under relevance in the Defualts section of the mesh.

[image: Mesh details]

Kind regards,
George Packham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is based on the fact that the user has an older version of Ansys, in this case user has 16.2. There is the option for lines and quadratic nodes but it is found under automatic method as Element midside nodes. The option are either dropped (linear) or kept(quadratic).

The issue arose as my colleagues are using the new version whilst my licence is an older model

Answer (score 3):

I dont have a direct solution for your problem but you might want to check your software version. If you are using the student version of ANSYS there might be a difference to the version you are using in class. And keep in mind that the student version is very limited regarding the number of nodes and elements you can use!

Comment: Thanks. I’ve actually solved it, I have an older version one Ansys and the option is found in a different place, under a different name. we’re also limited to 1000 elements anyway so not an issue